# cant run the client side on browser using websocket

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet

I want to create a real time Web chat app.

And trying to do it with ratchet. As a beginner I am not able to understand where I m Goin wrong. I have copied the whole Content from socketo.me and it worked in terminal using "telnet localhost 8080" but when I want to achieve the same thing using my browser it doesn't.

I put localhost:8080 in url and shows blank, where I want to view my index.php.

Plz help me. Where the localhost:8080 is pointing and where should I place my index. Php

[image: my directory looks like this]

Comment: What kind of server you've installed ?

Comment: look I am beginner to this.
and have node.js installed

Comment: It's a websocket you should not access is with a browser. You need to create a javascript that will listen and push to your websocket.

Comment: @mark it is working when i use telnet localhost 8080 but I want to make it functional in browser

Comment: If you read the code which you copy&pasted then you would of seen the part at the **bottom** of this page http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world#next_steps

Answer (score 0):

You have to create html file containing javascript for you to able to communicate with your websocket server, please refer to ratchet docs (http://socketo.me/docs/push#client).

```
<script src="https://gist.githubusercontent.com/cboden/fcae978cfc016d506639c5241f94e772/raw/e974ce895df527c83b8e010124a034cfcf6c9f4b/autobahn.js"></script>
<script>
    var conn = new ab.Session('ws://localhost:8080',
        function() {
            conn.subscribe('kittensCategory', function(topic, data) {
                // This is where you would add the new article to the DOM (beyond the scope of this tutorial)
                console.log('New article published to category "' + topic + '" : ' + data.title);
            });
        },
        function() {
            console.warn('WebSocket connection closed');
        },
        {'skipSubprotocolCheck': true}
    );
</script>
```

use google chrome console to see the logs (F12)

Comment: and how to load that html file in my browser.
I mean i m trying localhost:8080 to get it.

Comment: right click the html file > open with > google chrome

Comment: huh...thats simple.
i was expecting like : to load a php site we go localhost/sitename/index.php to run it.

Comment: you dont have to access http://localhost:8080, you have to create a separate server for your webserver. please take note that you only setup a websocket server not a webserver.

Comment: No, you don't have to. It's a communication between clientside / serverside so you have to add a javascript listener w/c is by ws:// protocol not http.

Btw, by following http://socketo.me/docs/push#client you can understand how it works